# Issue Running Python 3.7 in PyCharm to Execute Twitter Bot (via Tweepy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, pycharm, tweepy

I am attempting to run Python 3.7 code within PyCharm to execute a Twitter bot from Tweepy (Twitter's API).

-I have a developer account with Twitter, which has been approved.
-I have my correct consumer keys and access tokens within the code (these are left blank in this ticket).
-I have my correct Twitter handle within the code as well (left blank in this ticket's code as well).
-Tweepy has been added as a project interpreter to my bot project, and is using the same Python 3.7 interpreter.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tweepy
import random
import time

#Do not Touch Lists
followed = []
friends = []
liked = []
time_start = time.time()
first_run = 0

# 1. Log onto twitter
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
handle = '@MyHandle'
delay_between_search = 30

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


def findtweets():
# Find 'new' tweets (under hashtags/search terms)
terms = ["test"]
query = random.choice(terms)
search = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, result_type="recent", lang="en").items(35) #Change the amount of tweets being searched for 50-75
print("Searching under term..." + query)
# Like 'new' tweets (only if the user has more than 10 followers & less than 15000 tweets)
for tweet in search:
    if (tweet.user.followers_count < 10 and tweet.user.statuses_count < 15000):
        print("Ignoring user " + tweet.user.screen_name)
        continue
    try:
        api.create_favorite(id=tweet.id)
        print("Following user " + tweet.user.screen_name)
        # Follow the user, and then mute them.
        time.sleep(6)
        api.create_friendship(id=tweet.user.id)
        time.sleep(3)
        api.create_mute(id=tweet.user.id)
        # Store their name in a file to be reviewed later.
        followed.append(tweet.user.id)
        liked.append(tweet.id)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        #Catching errors
        if (e.args[0][0]['code'] == 139):
            print ("Error with tweet " + str(tweet.id) + ", already liked!")
            liked.append(tweet.id)
            continue
        if (e.args[0][0]['code'] == 88):
            print ("Rate limited..")
            time.sleep(60*15)
            continue
        print ("Error with tweet " + str(tweet.id))

# Unfollow() provides a method for unfollowing users that have not 
followed you back. Unfollow() also
# adds users that have followed you back to your "friends" list to 
be unfollowed at a later time.
def unfollow():
print(" ~ Starting unfollow process ~ ")
for user in followed:
    try:
        status = api.show_friendship(source_screen_name=handle, 
target_id=user)
    except:
        print ("Rate Limit Exceeded")
        time.sleep(900)
    # If the user is not following me back:
    if (str(status[1].following) == "False"):
        try:
            # Unfollow them
            api.destroy_friendship(id=user)
            time.sleep(10)
            print("Unfollowed: " + str(user))
            followed.remove(user)
            continue
        except:
            print("Could not Unfollow: " + str(user))
    # Save the names of those who followed us back.
    friends.append(user)
    print("Friended: " + str(user))
    followed.remove(user)

# Unfollow_friends(): Unfollows users that DO follow you back.
def unfollow_friends():
print(" ~ Starting unfollow_friends process ~ ")
for user in friends:
    try:
        api.destroy_friendship(id=user)
        print("Unfollowed: " + str(user))
        friends.remove(user)
    except:
        print("Could not Unfollow: " + str(user))

# Unlike statuses liked with the bot
def unlike():
for tweet in liked:
    try:
        api.destroy_favorite(id=tweet)
        print("Unliked: " + str(tweet))
        liked.remove(tweet)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        if(e.args[0][0]['code'] == 144):
            print("This status no longer exists... removing..")
            liked.remove(tweet)
            continue
        print("An unknown error occured")

# Write our actions to separate files in case of a error
def write_to_file(filename, list):
for item in list:
    filename.write(str(item) + "\n")

# Read from our files on first run.
if (first_run == 0):
try:
    with open('followed_users.txt') as f:
        followed = f.read().splitlines()
        if (len(followed) > 100):
            unfollow()
    with open('liked_tweets.txt') as f:
        liked = f.read().splitlines()
        if (len(liked) > 100):
            unlike()
    with open('friend_users.txt') as f:
        friends = f.read().splitlines()
        if (len(friends) > 100):
            unfollow_friends()
except:
    print("Files not found...waiting for first run.")
first_run = 1

while (1 > 0):
since_launch = int(time.time() - time_start)

print ("Running Twitter Bot... " + str(since_launch/60) + " minutes since last mass-action..")

# Tweeting
if (time.time() > time_start+(3600*3)):
    time_start = time.time()
    unfollow_friends()
if (time.time() > time_start+3600 and len(followed) > 100):
    unfollow()
    unlike()

findtweets()
time.sleep(delay_between_search)

# Logging
print("Logging our files...")
liked_tweets = open("liked_tweets.txt", "w")
write_to_file(liked_tweets, liked)
liked_tweets.close()
followed_users = open("followed_users.txt", "w")
write_to_file(followed_users, followed)
followed_users.close()
friend_users = open("friend_users.txt", "w")
write_to_file(friend_users, friends)
friend_users.close()
```

Running the code should expect for the bot to search and follow/like Tweets based on the search term, but I'm not getting that far. I am experiencing the following error(s):

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /Users/myname/Downloads/yt-python-twitter-master/twitter_bot.py
Files not found...waiting for first run.
Running Twitter Bot... 0.0 minutes since last mass-action..
Searching under term...test
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/myname/Downloads/yt-python-twitter-master/twitter_bot.py", line 48, in findtweets
api.create_favorite(id=tweet.id)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
return method.execute()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 429

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/myname/Downloads/yt-python-twitter-master/twitter_bot.py", line 158, in <module>
findtweets()
File "/Users/myname/Downloads/yt-python-twitter-master/twitter_bot.py", line 60, in findtweets
if (e.args[0][0]['code'] == 139):
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Status code 429 means you have reached your limit. Have a look at: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes.html

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided doesn't seem to be properly formatted.

However, a 429 [response status code](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes) means that you're being [rate limited](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html) by Twitter's API.
The rate limit for the [favorites/create endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-favorites-create) that `API.create_favorite` uses is 1000 requests / 24-hour window.

As for your handling of the resulting error, `e.args[0]` is the reason for the error in the form of a string.
See https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/error.py.
`e.args[0][0]` is therefore the first character of that reason.
Hence, the error you're encountering is because you're attempting to access a string (a single character) with the index `'code'`.